# Clarifying a Computation involving Partition of Unity and Convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, geometric-measure-theory

In Evans and Gariepy (p174) there is a proof showing the senses in which smooth functions approximate functions of bounded variation. There is the following computation -- the last step of which I'm confused by. They also say that $\sum D\zeta_k = 0$, how are they obtaining this fact?

Some notation: $\zeta_k$ is a smooth partition of unity on the set $U$. Imagine dividing $U$ into rings -- $\zeta_k$ is supported on 3 of these rings (precise statement given in reference). $\eta_k$ is a standard mollifier:

[image]

The computation:

[image]

Comment: Partition of unity means $\sum \zeta_k=1$ on $U$, so its gradient is zero.